# number multiplied by 1.0 getting different result than not multiplying it by 1.0 c#

Tags: c#

I was showing my cousin some of the beginner code that I was doing 6 months ago when I started coding and I encountered something strange that I can't explain to myself now that I know more about coding.

```
int countLight = 2;
int countModerate = 1;
int countStrong = 1;
int countVeryStrong = 1;
int count = countLight + countModerate + countStrong + countVeryStrong;

double percentLight = countLight * 1.0 / count * 100;
double percentModerate = countModerate * 1.0 / count * 100;
double percentStrong = countStrong * 1.0 / count * 100;
double percentVeryStrong = countVeryStrong * 1.0 / count * 100;

Console.WriteLine($"Light: {percentLight:F2}%");
Console.WriteLine($"Moderate: {percentModerate:F2}%");
Console.WriteLine($"Strong: {percentStrong:F2}%");
Console.WriteLine($"Very Strong: {percentVeryStrong:F2}%");
```

The thing I am wondering about is the "multiplied by 1.0" part. When I do the math on a paper it doesn't matter if I will multiply by 1.0 or I will not, I will get the same answer.
This is what I get with letting the 1.0 stay - the actual answer(the code is correct):

```
Light: 40.00%
Moderate: 20.00%
Strong: 20.00%
Very Strong: 20.00%
```

When I remove the "1.0" I get this:

```
Light: 0.00%
Moderate: 0.00%
Strong: 0.00%
Very Strong: 0.00%
```

For example : 3 * 1.0 = 3; 3 = 3; there should be no difference in the result, but here there is. I would be glad if someone can explain this to me.

Comment: Multiplying by 1.0 converts an `int` value into a `double`. Without it you get integer division, where e.g. 1/3 == 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In statements like this:

```
double percentLight = countLight / count * 100;
```

The expression on the right side is done using **integer arithmetics**, because all the values are intergers.
If `count` is larger than `countLight`, then `countLight / count` will be `0` (integer division yields result without the fraction part), and multiplying by 100 will keep it a `0`.

On the other hand in statements like this:

```
double percentLight = countLight * 1.0 / count * 100;
```

In order to calculate `countLight * 1.0`, `countLight` is converted to `double` to match `1.0`. The result is simply `countLight` as a `double` and by multiplying by `100` you get the value you expected because [**floating-point arithmetic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) is applied.

You can achieve the same by **casting**, e.g.:

```
double percentLight = (double)countLight / count * 100;
```

Since we cast `countLight` to a `double`, the expression will have the same value as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

When in c#, when multiplying `int` by `double` you get a `double`, but when you multiply by `int` you get `int`, same for division.

For example -

```
10 * 0.1 / 4 = 2.5
10 / 4 = 2.0
```